# Do "Bodies Found" Count Against Ghosting?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

Does anyone know if an enemy discovering the body of one of his sleeping comrades counts against you for a "Ghost" run? i.e. Not if they get any bolts in the 'detected' meter over their head, but if they just see the fellow thug/guard/etc and say something like "Hey! Wake up!". I was just wondering since it seems to show this stat on the summary screen after a mission and I thought this might mean it's important.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't. Here is proof from my recent stealthy, super-lethal playthrough of '[House of Pleasure](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Pleasure)' mission stats (With no [Shadow Kill](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Kill). Notice that there are 12 bodies found, but 'Ghost' is checked):
[image]

Basically, as long as [no red 'marker' appears on an NPC or a wolfhound (dog), it won't count as detected. Three white 'markers' won't count as detected.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90105/4797) The red marker appears only if an NPC or wolfhound has detected you, not a body you killed or made unconscious.

Also, here are some reports from other posts:

> Bodies found does not void the achievements Ghost, Clean hands or Shadow. Completed all three achievements yesterday and I have had missions where bodies were found.

[Source (Reddit /r/dishonored)](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11skn9/does_this_void_the_achievement/c6pfrky)

Other reports: [[1]](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11arpe/what_counts_as_an_alarm_i_cant_seem_to_get_a/c6ktbi5) [[2]](http://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/11skn9/does_this_void_the_achievement/c6pko8j)

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not.  I was awarded both Shadow/Ghost on my play-through and I ended up with several bodies discovered in the mission statistics for quite a few missions.

Comment: But it does affect the chaos negatively if you're going for the low chaos achievement as you can see in the pic. the guy uploaded.

Comment: High chaos is a result of killing mostly, if you render people unconscious and their bodies are found I don't believe that adds to higher chaos, but it does count in the "Bodies found" number. You can get Clean Hands and Ghost if you don't kill anyone, regardless of # bodies found.