# Possible to get Ghost (Never detected) but kill everyone?

Tags: dishonored

If you're able to kill everyone without being seen (red bolt above their head) will you still get ghost?

Goes by the joke, "You can't get detected if there's no one to detect."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the 'Mission Stats' checkbox is concerned - yes, it is possible. Here is proof from a stealthy, super-lethal playthrough of mine of the '[House of Pleasure](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Pleasure)' mission (with no [Shadow Kill](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Kill)). In the screenshot of the mission stats below, notice that there are 44 hostiles killed, 'Didn't Kill Anyone' is not checked, but 'Ghost (Never Detected)' is checked:

[image: House of Pleasure missions stats]

Basically, as long as [no red 'marker' appears on an NPC or a wolfhound (dog), it won't count as detected. Three white 'markers' won't count as detected.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90105/4797)

<sub>(Parts of this post are copied from [an answer of mine in the question, Do “Bodies Found” Count Against Ghosting?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90196/4797))</sub>

Comment: Hey do you know if you can still get Ghost (the tickbox, not the achievement) if you try to execute your target from the front (to get the awesome kill animation)?  I mean to do it fast enough that as soon as he turns you press kill, so no red 'marker' manages to pop before their head falls off, does that work?  Or is that an automatic detection?

Comment: @Lightbrand I haven't tested that. But theoretically, as long as [no red 'marker' appears, it won't count as detected](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90105/4797) for the purposes of the 'Ghost' mission stats checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

If they are not aware of you, before you attack them, it counts as a stealth kill and ghost will still be awarded. Most players tend to stack the no kill achievements with Ghost though.

This also applies to sleeping darts and other non lethal and lethal take downs. Obviously pistols are ruled out since they make others detect you.

Comment: Thanks, no kill with ghost is too boring of a run for me.  Rather do 2 runs, high chaos (kill everyone) + ghost.  And a low chaos, Blink spam to objective and finish non-lethal even if gets detected.

Answer (score 1):

Killing will invalidate [the achievement](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost):

> Complete all missions after the prologue, alerting or killing no one but the key targets

You can, however, knock them all unconscious to the same effect. You can't get detected if there's no one awake to detect you.

Killing will not invalidate the [end of mission checkbox](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/10/08/dishonored-how-to-get-low-chaos-no-kills-and-ghost-ratings-no-spoilers/):

> All characters and creatures count as detecting the player character, with the exception of friendly characters, Rats, River Krust, Hagfish and Watchtowers. This is evidenced by the red bolt icons upon detection.
>
> Friendly characters will turn into a detection if they see your character do anything aggressive/hostile (kill someone, be hostile towards the NPC, carry a dead/subdued body, etc.). They will gain the red bolts when this happens.

So all you really need to do for this is go undetected and get no red bolts.