Does the Ghost achievement require no kills?
The Ghost achievement writes:

Complete all missions after the prologue, alerting no one or killing no one but key targets.

I originally thought it means to choose from the two, 1. alerting no one, or 2. killing no one but key targets. To this explanation, just alerting nobody would get this achievement, although with kills.
However, I just read a post, which seems to say that killing will invalidate this achievement. This suggests that maybe my explanation is incorrect.
The post: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/129898/275353
To sum up, can I kill and still get the Ghost achievement?

I completed the game as a pacifist and got the Clean Hands achievement. I did not get the Ghost achievement.
Therefore, it is necessary to do both: Kill no one but key targets, and not alert anyone.
There's a separate "Shadow" achievement that just says "...without alerting anyone" and no mention of killing, so I suspect that is what you'll get if you kill people without ever being alerted.

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129894/possible-to-get-ghost-never-detected-but-kill-everyone states otherwise

That may simply be the end of level report, and separate from the achievement. I can't absolutely state that killing people but otherwise ghosting the entire game will grant the Ghost achievement, but if that is the case, then it's a copy of the "Shadow" achievement, which would be odd.
