# Does it count against ghosting a mission if you're seen by a weeper?

Tags: dishonored

Ghosting a mission is defined as never even having been detected at the end of a mission. Weepers aren't exactly "sentient", really, but they have similar detection mechanics to the other, more intelligent enemies in the game.

If I'm detected by a weeper, will I lose the "ghost" of the mission, so long as no other enemies see me?

Comment: "*Weepers do count for detection. They do raise the Chaos level if they are killed.*" Source: [Notes on Stealth Detection, Chaos, and Trophies/Achievements](https://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1415445-notes-on-stealth-detection-chaos-and-trophiesachievements/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, being detected by anything that triggers the bolts (and thus the [relevant red bolts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90016/)) [does count](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/dishonored/175533-ghost-weeper-detection.html) as being detected.

The only exception to this are the key assassination targets (and [hagfish, devices and rats that turn hostile](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored/Ghost)) - those do not count against Ghost/Shadow and the [related achievement](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost).