# Does Ghost in Dishonored reset when loading?

Tags: dishonored

So I was playing through the campaign, achievement hunting, and I took a look at [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90016/do-white-bolts-not-count-as-being-detected) pertaining to the three white bolts meaning NOT detected. Only when it turns red.

Only issue is - when I went through the mission, I got to the very end, and then got detected.  I let them slice me in little pieces so i could just load the save that I was at and continue on.

I loaded back before I was detected, and i finished the mission only to find that Ghost wasn't checked..

Does reloading the save even have an effect on this feat? or do I have to play the mission all over again until i go through the entirety of the mission undetected?

Comment: Reloading a save should be enough, I've done that plenty of times. You may have been detected without knowing it, or you've encountered a bug. Or maybe you should've just manually reloaded the save after getting detected, instead of dying.

Comment: those all could have been likely options.. hmm.. guess I'll have to do it over again to find out:P

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the save should work, but if you were seen then saved you saved the state of having lost Ghost. Restart the entire mission (from the first mission where you lost Ghost) and be more careful when saving. It is sometimes hard to tell when you have been detected or killed someone in Dishonored since the only certain report on Ghost/kill count is after the level is over.

Comment: I for sure didn't get detected before the save. I'm not daft :)

Comment: @sircapsalot well I'm sure loading a save before detection is safe, I've done that several dozen or hundred times during my Ghost playthrough. Blessed be the quicksave

Comment: unfortunately i don't have that blessing `:(` borrowing it from a friend for 360.. i'm assuming autosave is for pc

Comment: @sircapsalot oh yes I play on PC, is there really no quicksave button? In that case I would be much more careful about saving